# multiplication table in a textbox

Tags: vb.net

you will probably have to run the program to understand, but i want my loop:

```
For i = 1 To final
txttable.Text += vbCrLf + CStr(i) + " "
Next
```

to be in the same line as the rest.

so it looks something like this if i enter 5

```
  5 

    1 2 3 4 5

 1  1 2 3 4 5
 2  2 4 6 8 10
 3  3 6 8 12 15
 ... to 5
```

txttable.Text is a textbox

maybe i will have to rewrite some of my code to make it work, dont be shy if you have any suggestions

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim final As Integer
    Integer.TryParse(txtfinal.Text, final)
    Select Case final
        Case 2 To 20
            txttable.Text = (final).ToString + vbCrLf
            For i = 1 To final
                txttable.Text += vbCrLf + CStr(i) + " "
            Next
            For i = 1 To final
                txttable.Text += vbTab + CStr(i) + " "
            Next
            txttable.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
            txttable.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
            For ligne As Integer = 1 To final
                For col As Integer = 1 To final
                    txttable.Text += vbTab + (ligne * col).ToString
                Next
                txttable.Text += vbCrLf
            Next
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("veuillez entrez une valeur entre 2 et 20 inclusivement")
            txtfinal.Clear()
            txtfinal.Focus()
    End Select
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: In VB.Net the preferred concatenation of strings is the `&` operator so `&=` is valid too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim final As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(txtfinal.Text, final) Then
        If final >= 2 AndAlso final <= 20 Then
            Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            sb.AppendLine(final.ToString)

            For col As Integer = 1 To final
                sb.Append(vbTab & col.ToString() & " ")
            Next
            sb.Append(vbCrLf & vbCrLf)

            For row As Integer = 1 To final
                sb.Append(row.ToString)

                For col As Integer = 1 To final
                    sb.Append(vbTab & (row * col).ToString)
                Next

                sb.Append(vbCrLf)
            Next

            txttable.Text = sb.ToString
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    MessageBox.Show("veuillez entrez une valeur entre 2 et 20 inclusivement")
    txtfinal.Clear()
    txtfinal.Focus()
End Sub
```

Which produced:

```
5
    1   2   3   4   5 

1   1   2   3   4   5
2   2   4   6   8   10
3   3   6   9   12  15
4   4   8   12  16  20
5   5   10  15  20  25
```

when 5 was entered.